# AFNetworking fails to create a request on a GET request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to make a get request to a restful service. This request has worked for the last 3 weeks when I was using a request without a request manager. As soon as I added a request manager because I wanted to send a dictionary of parameters, the code keeps crashing with the error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: urlRequest'
```

My code is as follows. The commented out code still works if I uncomment it and replace the new code with it. Why am I able to make a request from that URL but not with AFNetworking?

```
NSString *URLForSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/", ([_remoteDownloadURLString stringByAppendingString:_getFilesJsonURLString]),_userName ];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLForSend];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    self.downloadJsonRequest = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];//this works to create a a afhttprequestoperation, with the same url
    _downloadJsonRequest.responseSerializer =
    [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers];
    __unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    NSMutableDictionary *mutDictForSend = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"tokenInfo"]];
    [mutDictForSend removeObjectForKey:@"success"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
    [manager GET:URLForSend parameters:mutDictForSend success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {

         NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
         weakSelf.jsonArrayForCaching = responseObject;
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kBIDContentEndingSync object:weakSelf];
         [weakSelf gotNewJson:responseObject];
     }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Request Failure Because %@",[error userInfo]);
     }];
    /*
    [_downloadJsonRequest setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {

         NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
         weakSelf.jsonArrayForCaching = responseObject;
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kBIDContentEndingSync object:weakSelf];
         [weakSelf gotNewJson:responseObject];
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Request Failure Because %@",[error userInfo]);
     }];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kBIDContentStartingSync object:self];
    [_downloadJsonRequest start];
     */
```

Comment: Unrelated, but if there's a chance that `self` might be deallocated before the request is done, I'd suggest using `__weak` instead of `__unsafe_unretained`, as the latter could result in `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. You can also retire `request` and `self.downloadJsonRequest` as your new code isn't using them and is only a source of confusion. Finally, if you really need the response to be a mutable object, you might want to set the `manager.responseSerializer` like you were setting `self.downloadJsonRequest.responseSerializer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest replacing the line:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
```

With

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
```

The latter calls `initWithBaseURL`, which does some configuration of the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, that just calling `[[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init]` does not appear to do.

If you're still having issues even doing that, I'd suggest adding [Exception Breakpoint](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/devfeaa874d0) to identify precisely where this exception is taking place.

Comment: You are completely correct, just caught it 2 second ago, but your answer is much better ;) thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was a tough one, but it turns out that `requestOperationManager` is a singleton so I should not have initialised him, but call its instance...